# svn creating a tag of tags

Tags: svn, tags

I have multiple applications in a single repo.  They each have their own branch/trunk/tag folders.  Is there a way I can create a tag of tags.  The idea being each application has their own version but I want to have a overall system version (indicating these versions of applications are known to work correctly with each other).  Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can

Tag of tags is ordinary node (preferably outside projects-tree, smth. like `/VERSIONS/.../`) inside which you'll copy real tags of your apps (or link tags with PEG-ged externals): you can have any tree inside repository, `trunk/branches/tags` is just well-established convention

Comment: is there a way to do this in one command or does it have to be done by several copy commands?

Comment: @user3725358 - it will be at least two commands: mkdir + copy "When copying multiple sources, they will be added as children of DST, which must be a directory."